# group-wise linear models function nest_by

Tags: r, model, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataframe of 4 columns: Dataset, X, Y, Group.

The task is to fit a linear model to each of the five groups (The group column contains 5 groups: a, b, c, d, e) in the dataframe and then compare the slope with the dataframe test_2. For the test_2 I have already fitted a model, as there was no group separation like in the test_1. For the test_1 we have been suggested to use the function nest_by to compute a group-wise linear models
I have tried to fit a model with the function `nest_by`

**Input**:

```
model <- test_1 %>%
nest_by(Group) %>%
mutate(model = list(lm(y ~ x, data = test_1)))
model
```

**Output**:

```
A tibble: 5 x 3
# Rowwise:  Group
Group               data model 
<fct> <list<tibble[,3]>> <list>
1 a               [58 x 3] <lm>  
2 b               [35 x 3] <lm>  
3 c               [47 x 3] <lm>  
4 d               [44 x 3] <lm>  
5 e               [38 x 3] <lm>
```

I do not know now how to proceed. I thought that I could ungroup them and do a summary(), but would be similar to just fit a model separately with the function filter() and create 5 separated models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can proceed further using `tidy` from broom package which is better option than `summary` and then doing `unnest`.

For example, for `mtcars`, for each cyl group, we can do the following,

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

mtcars_model <- mtcars %>% 
  nest(data = -cyl) %>% 
  mutate(
    model = map(data,  ~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))
  )
 
# now simply for each cyl, tidy the model output and unnest it
 
mtcars_model %>% 
  mutate(
    tidy_summary = map(model, tidy)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tidy_summary)

#> # A tibble: 6 × 8
#>     cyl data               model  term      estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <dbl> <list>             <list> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   (Interce…    28.4      4.18       6.79 1.05e-3
#> 2     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <lm>   wt           -2.78     1.33      -2.08 9.18e-2
#> 3     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   (Interce…    39.6      4.35       9.10 7.77e-6
#> 4     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <lm>   wt           -5.65     1.85      -3.05 1.37e-2
#> 5     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   (Interce…    23.9      3.01       7.94 4.05e-6
#> 6     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <lm>   wt           -2.19     0.739     -2.97 1.18e-2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**For additional Information with examples, check [here](https://broom.tidymodels.org/articles/broom_and_dplyr.html)**

Comment: That is great thank you so much! It is way better and less tricky compared to what I was trying to do.